# Windows batch script for processing filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create simply batch script to copy my folders from my user profile to NAS using robocopy. I have written the script but it is not working. I have two files one is the script and second is the text file where I will put the folder paths to be copied to NAS. The scipt will use this text file. Following are the code snippets,
batch file:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%v in (dir.txt) do (
echo:%%v
robocopy %%v h:\ 
)
```

text file (dir.txt)

```
"%userprofile%\desktop"
"%userprofile%\downloads"
"%userprofile%\My Documents"
"%userprofile%\Documents"
"%userprofile%\Favorites"
```

the batch script is unable to process file names from variable.

Thanks

Comment: Are the folders that need to be copied always subdirectories of %userprofile%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if this answer is naive, but can you alter the source file? If it was simply this:

```
\desktop
\downloads
\My Documents
\Documents
\Favorites
```

You could use this batch file:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%v in (dir.txt) do (
echo:"%userprofile%%%v"
robocopy "%userprofile%%%v" h:\ 
)
```

If there is some reason that the userprofile of the one executing the command does not work, maybe make a batch program that generates the initial input file with the correct paths already spelled out.

Comment: HI Gray,thats cool. Its working for me. Do you know why it does not take the userprofile in the script.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I think it is because you are passing basically a literal string to the command rather than something it needs to interpret. Why does it work that way? I do not know. There may be some way to make it work with what you did by basically using the call command and piping the output? Not sure if that would work, but this is a much simpler solution (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

As CharlesB suggested, I would write a script like this in PowerShell. It is much easier to use than batch scripts.

I think this script will do what you want:

```
cat dirs.txt | ForEach {
    $dirPath = $_ -replace  "%userprofile%", $env:userprofile
    Write-Host $dirPath
    robocopy $dirPath h:\
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestions. We have lots of Windows XP installed and we want to keep a consistent set of script along the organization.

Comment: It is possible to install PowerShell on XP but you probably don't want  to do that...

Comment: yes quite right just want to leverage the current tools i.e batch script.